# Graphview legend position

Tags: android-graphview

I can place the legend top, middle, bottom, but its always on the right side of the graphview. How can I place it left side?

The most important problem that "too long" texts doesn't fit in the box, so the end of the text is outside the box / screen. I know I can change the text size, but I don't want to solve the problem in this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved my problem:

```
graph.getLegendRenderer().resetStyles();
```

Just called if I need to resize the legend box.

Answer (score 0):

in the current version it's also possible to freely set the position of legend and also the width